# Implementing 2-way binding for Combobox SelectedItem in Windows Store

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have a small problem with Combobox bindings in Windows Store app. It has to be bound to localized enumeration values (enumeration name is BackgroundTrack). I have 2 properties in view model - items list and selected item. I use Tuple<,> to hold enumeration value and its localized string representation.

Property for selected item in vm:

```
public Tuple<BackgroundTrack, String> SelectedBackgroundTrack
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedBackgroundTrack;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_selectedBackgroundTrack == null ||
            _selectedBackgroundTrack.Equals(value))
        {
            _selectedBackgroundTrack = value;
            _settingsService.BackgroundTrack = value.Item1;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedBackgroundTrack");
        }
    }
}
```

Property for items list in vm:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<BackgroundTrack, String>> BackgroundTrackList { get; set; }
```

Combobox bindings:

```
            <ComboBox 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BackgroundTrackList}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedBackgroundTrack, Mode=TwoWay}"
             Grid.Row="10" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}"
            />
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
             <Grid>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2}"/>
             </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

ViewModel constructor:

```
BackgroundTrackList = EnumUtils.GetLiterals<BackgroundTrack>();
SelectedBackgroundTrack = BackgroundTrackList.First(t => t.Item1.Equals(_settingsService.BackgroundTrack));
```

Problem: I'm setting selected item (from app settings) in ViewModel constructor, but this value does not show in combobox - it has nothing selected. If I select something in combobbox, the binding works correctly and sets the underlying ViewModel property. How do I correct this issue? Do I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged or defer setting of selected item property programatically?

Comment: Make sure getter of SelectedItem property when hit, your ItemsSource is loaded otherwise you have to implement INPC and raise event to notify UI that property has changed of SelectedItem.

Comment: I have implemented INPC and I'm hitting setter in constructor, raising  property changed. Still combobox has empty selection at start. (Question has been updated)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `IEquatable<T>` on the type that is used for the item. `Tuple` does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValuePath` at same time.

If you are using SelectedItem, `remove SelectedValuePath` and it will work as expected.

Comment: I have implemented changes per your advice, still it does not work. I have updated question code to reflect the changes.

Comment: Don't remove `DisplayMemberPath`. Only remove `SelectedValuePath`. `DisplayMemberPath` is needed to show selected text in combobox.

Comment: I've tested with <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BackgroundTrackList}" DisplayMemberPath="Item2" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedBackgroundTrack, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="10" /> - still no luck.

Comment: Hmm you need to update samll sample reproducing this problem because this works in small app i tried.

Comment: You got it working in Win Store? Can you please share you app? Thank you.